# adding interpretations

Tags: scheme, racket

excuse me if this is a dumb question, but I just want to know what exactly do they mean by this?

```
 (define-struct squar (x y size outline c))
```

"Add interpretations for the Square  class"

I've tried looking this up online, but nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no universal or commonly accepted meaning for the world "interpretations" as applied to structs.  Without coming to terms, I can't help very much.  You'll need to talk with your instructor in order to reach a common understanding of the terms, because I'm as lost as you are right now.  :)  Are you positively sure your instructor used the word "interpretations"?  That does not sound right for some reason.

Comment: yes, thats exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This
    (make-square 10 20 30 "solid" "red")
evaluates to a structure.

What does this structure represent?

The answer to the question, is an interpretation.

One reasonable interpretation, is to say the
above value represent a 30x30 square whose upper
left corner has screen coordinates (10,20) 
whose interior is filled (it is solid) with red 
color.

Comment: ... ok, that's one way to interpret what the question means by "interpretation".  :)

Comment: If the original poster gave a little more context, it would be easier to guide him in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. But thats ALL it says. "Add interpretations for the Square class" I wish he would elaborate more.